# delete functionality using JQuery

Tags: jquery, delete-row

Any suggestion on how to put a delete button?

Code :

```
function addProduct(name,price){
function add(){
    for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
        var row = data.rows[i];
        if (row.name == name){
            row.quantity += 1;
            return;
        }
    }
    data.total += 1;
    data.rows.push({
        name:name,
        quantity:1,
        price:price
    });
```

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/youmarky/fmM3e/10/)

Comment: @Youmarky, edit your question, and explain what you want to delete.

Comment: for example if the user will drag the item to the cart, the user can delete what they choose on the cart.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to add a button which call a function on the id of the <tr>. onClick you call for exemple deleteButton(buttonId) and you delete it.

document.getElementById('buttonId').remove()

Comment: Is jQuery used here at all? Also, why is the function _add_ inside _addProduct_?

Comment: Im sorry @Superdrac for un-understandable question, hehe im just newbie here.

Comment: Anyway i will just try your suggestion @Superdrac :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ALWAYS GOOGLE A BIT BEFORE POSTING A QUESTION :-)**

Refer to this page :

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid12.php

Add function similar to this:

```
function deleterow(target){
    $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure?',function(r){
        if (r){
            $('#tt').datagrid('deleteRow', getRowIndex(target));
        }
    });
}
```

They have given a very good documentation on the same

Comment: It could be more ease for him to create a button at same time that he add the product to his basket. 

And i'm not sure that he use jQuery

Comment: Yes, he use jQuery Easy UI. Check his fiddle..